# process out of memory when using Node and jsdom to spider site

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js, jsdom

I'm attempting to pull a string from a bunch of HTML pages that I have stored in an array. I have the following code:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
desc('Import pages');
task('handleSpots', [], function (params) {

  allSpots.forEach(function(spotUrl){
    handleSpot(spotUrl)
  })
});

function handleSpot (href) {
  jsdom.env(
    href,
    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
    function (err, window) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(host+href+" "+err)
        return
      }
      const data = {url: host+href}
      data['name'] = window.$("h1.wanna-item-title-title a").text()
      console.log(data['name'])
      window.close()
    }
  );
}
```

There are about 600 urls in the allSpots array. When I run this I get a bunch of errors:

```
/the_hook/index.html Error: read ECONNRESET
```

This happens to a bunch of the urls, some names are displayed and then finally I get this error.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

80660 ms: Scavenge 1355.3 (1460.0) -> 1355.3 (1460.0) MB, 2.3 / 0 ms (+ 1.4 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
82149 ms: Mark-sweep 1355.3 (1460.0) -> 1354.8 (1460.0) MB, 1488.7 / 0 ms (+ 2.8 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.4 ms) [last resort gc].
83657 ms: Mark-sweep 1354.8 (1460.0) -> 1354.6 (1460.0) MB, 1508.2 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x38f1b4237339 <JS Object>
    1: create [native v8natives.js:~755] [pc=0x22e6902f1923] (this=0x38f1b4236b61 <JS Function Object (SharedFunctionInfo 0x38f1b4236ad1)>,an=0x1590d58f6941 <an Object with map 0x1b19e3c1e251>,aD=0x38f1b4204131 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
    3: createImpl [/Users/craig/Programming/node_wannasurf_importer/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Text.js:~90] [pc=0x22e...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Abort trap: 6
```

This only happens if there are more than 125 items in the allSpots array. Fewer than that and everything works fine.

I'm pretty new to node but I'm assuming that Javascript is attempting to get too many of these pages at the same time and is eventually running out of memory. Ideally I could write something that handles 100, waits until that's done then moves on to the next 100.

I tried this:
    async.eachLimit(allSpots, 100, handleSpot)
But that only handles the first 100 then stops.

I also tried:
   async.eachSeries(allSpots, handleSpot)
But this only deals with the first url and stops.

I'm at a bit of a dead end so I'd really appreciate any advice anyone can give me.
Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 3):

I decided to drop jsdom and replaced it with cheerio and https so that I might have a little more control of the request process. Then I worked out how to synchronously request each url (using on('end') on the request) then started processing the urls in a loop, so the number of times the loops iterates is the number of concurrent processes.

Here's the code:

```
const https = require('https');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

desc('Import pages');
task('handleSpots', [], function (params) {
  var totalLoop = 10;
  for( var i = 0; i < totalLoop; i++ ) {
    handleSpotAndNext()
  }
});

function handleSpotAndNext() {
  spot = allSpots.pop()
  https.get(spot,function(res){
    var chunks = '';
    res.on('data',function(d){
      chunks += d;
    });
    res.on('end',function(){
      console.log(spotData(chunks, spot))
      if(allSpots.length){
        handleSpotAndNext();
      }
    })
  })

}

function spotData(spotHtml, url) {
  $ = cheerio.load(spotHtml)
  const data = {url: url}
  data['name'] = $("h1.wanna-item-title-title a").text() 
  return data
}
```

This is what I came up with but if you see this and can think of a more elegant solution it'd be great to hear from you.

Comment: I liked JSDOM because it's really a browser instance within NodeJS. But I didn't find a way to deallocate memory.

With Cheerio's tip, everything went well. The memory goes up, but soon it recycles and the memory returns. My code with JSDOM exceeded 4GB, but with Cheerio it didn't exceed 300MB and then went back to around 70MB.